# JavaScript variable definition and scope

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I'm trying to understand how variable scope works when you bind an event.

The following example works fine:

```
function clickHandler() {
    alert(foo);
}

var foo = true;

$('div').on({
    'click': clickHandler
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/OliverJAsh/7fM5U/4/

However, when I make this simple change, it doesn't work anymore:

```
function clickHandler() {
    alert(foo);
}

(function () {
    var foo = true;

    $('div').on({
        'click': clickHandler
    });
}());
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/OliverJAsh/7fM5U/3/

How would you go about making the second example work? Can I do anything with `.call`? I am wondering this because the function is being called where the variable is defined, so I want it to have access to that.

**UPDATE:**

I understand why it can't access the variable - but because the function is being called from where the variable is defined, I wondered how I could make it work, without moving the scope of things. I think I'm asking about the `.call` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript variables are scoped within functions - so the scope of foo is within your anonymous `(function () { .. }());` which is not visible to `clickHandler`.

To fix it you can bring the `clickHandler` function into the anonymous function like so:

```
(function () {
  var foo = true;
  var clickHandler = function() {
    alert(foo);
  }

  $('div').on({
    'click': clickHandler
  });
}());
```

**Update**

If you are unable to change the scoping if the clickHandler function and do not wish to change the signature either, you can use [the `call` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) like so:

```
function clickHandler () {
  alert(this);
}

(function () {
  var foo = true;
  $('div').on({
    'click': function() { clickHandler.call(foo); }
  });
}());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not an option in the script I am writing. Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 2):

If you declare a variable within a function using `var`, it will only be accessible *within* that function, or within functions that are declared *within* that function.

`clickHandler` is declared outside the function in which `foo` is declared, so it's not accessible.

If you move the declaration of `clickHandler` to be within the function, [you'll see it works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/7fM5U/5/);

```
(function () {
    var foo = true;


    function clickHandler() {
        alert(foo);
    }

    $('div').on({
        'click': clickHandler
    });
}());
```

If you can't move `clickHandler`, you'll have to modify it to access `foo` as a parameter;

```
function clickHandler(foo) {
    alert(foo);
}

(function () {
    var foo = true;

    $('div').on({
        'click': function () {
            // We can access `foo` here because the function is being declared within the scope of `foo`.
            clickHandler(foo);
        }
    });
}());
```

Comment: But I am calling a function where the variable is defined, so how can I make it access that? I don't really want to pass the variable as a parameter. Can I do anything with `.call`?

Answer (score 0):

because var foo is not publically defined.... try this code

```
var foo = true;
function clickHandler() {
    alert(foo);
}
(function () {
    foo = true;
    $('div').on({
        'click': clickHandler
    });
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

when you wrap the function with a anonymous function, the javascript parser parse all the block together and execute it as separate block.

you have to put the definition of your function `clickHandler` into the block